# paintComponent ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, swing, concurrentmodification

I'm writing an application in swing, and I have a component that draws objects that are being dragged. Here's a small section of the code:

```
public class DragPanel extends JComponent{

    private final int CARD_STACK_SPACING;
    private int x, y;
    private List<Card> cards;

    public DragPanel(int cardStackSpacing) {
        x = -1;
        y = -1;
        cards = null;
        CARD_STACK_SPACING = cardStackSpacing;
    }

    public void drag(int x, int y, Card card) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
        cards.add(card);
        repaint();
    }
    public void dragCards(int x, int y, List<Card> cards) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.cards = cards;
        repaint();
    }
    public void stopDragging() {
        x = -1;
        y = -1;
        cards = null;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if (x > 0 && y > 0) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            int adjustedY = y;
            for (int i = 0; i < cards.size(); ++i) {
                CardImager.drawCard(cards.get(i), g2d, x, adjustedY);
                adjustedY += CARD_STACK_SPACING;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when I run this code, I get a `ConcurrentModificationException`, which I think is because I have a for loop in `paintComponent` that iterates over the list of cards, and I also have methods that set the list of cards to something different.

My question is, what can I do to make sure this doesn't happen?

**Edit:** here's some more information, when the mouse is dragged, this method is called, which calls the dragCards method from dragPanel above.

```
@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    firstClick = 0;
    if (!isDragging &&
            !isDraggingStack &&
            e.getSource() instanceof ResultDisplay && 
            searchPanel.getCard(e.getX(), e.getY()) != null) {

        isDragging = true;
        draggingCard = searchPanel.getCard(e.getX(), e.getY());
        offsets = searchPanel.getOffsets(e.getX(), e.getY());
        dragPanel.drag(e.getX() + offsets[0], e.getY() + offsets[1], draggingCard);

    } else if (!isDragging &&
            !isDraggingStack &&
            e.getSource() instanceof DeckBuilderPanel &&
            deckBuilderPanel.getCard(e.getX(), e.getY()) != null) {

        isDraggingStack = true;
        offsets = deckBuilderPanel.getOffsets(e.getX(), e.getY());
        draggingCardStack = deckBuilderPanel.removeCardStack(e.getX(), e.getY());
        dragPanel.dragCards(e.getX() + offsets[0], e.getY() + offsets[1] + searchPanel.getHeight(), draggingCardStack);
        System.out.println(offsets[0] + " " + offsets[1]);
    }
    if (isDragging && !isDraggingStack) {
        dragPanel.drag(e.getX() + offsets[0], e.getY() + offsets[1], draggingCard);
    } else if (!isDragging && isDraggingStack) {
        dragPanel.dragCards(e.getX() + offsets[0], e.getY() + offsets[1] + searchPanel.getHeight(), draggingCardStack);
    }
}
```

Comment: You will probably need to show the code for this method: `CardImager.drawCard(cards.get(i), g2d, x, adjustedY);` Calling `get(...)` on an ArrayList should not cause a ConcurrentModificationException, so more must be going on, I think.

Comment: Also, at any point, are you changing the cards ArrayList, *while* you are iterating through it?

Comment: You could use a CopyOnWriteArrayList from NIO, but it might not be a good idea due to performance. What I suggest is you take a look at some synchronisation tutorials.

Comment: The CardImager.drawCard method doesn't modify the Card in any way.